# Pulling <s:variant> from atom feed with simple pie

Tags: php, shopify, simplepie, atom-feed

How can I get the title tag from the s:variant block below using simple pie?

```
<s:variant>
  <id>product_variants-96590662</id>
  <title>Default Title</title>
  <s:price currency="GBP">10.00</s:price>
  <s:sku>002</s:sku>
  <s:grams>0</s:grams>
</s:variant>
```

I've tried the following to avail, and also 'variant' and just 's'

```
$caption = $item->get_item_tags('http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom', 's:variant');
```

The feed in question is [here](http://shop.stighlorgan.com/collections/autumn-winter-eleven.atom) (from shopify), and the docs on get_item_tags is [here](http://simplepie.org/wiki/reference/simplepie_item/get_item_tags).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read the xml namespace for `s` from the `<feed>` tag.

```
<feed xmlns:s="http://jadedpixel.com/-/spec/shopify" xml:lang="en-US" xmlns:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
```

According to it you have to use `http://jadedpixel.com/-/spec/shopify` as the namespace parameter in `get_item_tags()`, and the second parameter is the tag name without the `s:`.

```
$varinat = $item->get_item_tags('http://jadedpixel.com/-/spec/shopify', 'variant');
```

Comment: The URL for the namespace returns a 404, does that matter?

Comment: There is a chance that the namespace they use is no longer supported by shopify. In that case this method may not work, even if the parameters are good now. I would try doing a full parse, and dump the result, maybe you can get what you need that way.

Comment: Hmm seems to chuck me back a slightly smaller array, which is more workable. Thanks.